# ScrollView, I can't scroll to see top of the content

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `LinearLayout` with `layout_gravity="bottom"` inside a `ScrollView`

The problem is when the content reach the top of the `ScrollView` I can't scroll to see the top of this content.
[image: Problem 1]

I only can scroll to see the bottom of the screen but i can see only empty space .

[image: problem 2]

This is my Layout `XML` Code :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.projects.zak_dev.errors.MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can someone help me please !

Comment: because any layout start with in top of the layout. if you want to see space in top the set margin in top.

Comment: @Destro i am trying to create a chat app .. you know we scroll to see the old messages and always the new messages came from the bottom .

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`.

To get to the bottom of your ScrollView, add `android:id="@+id/scrollView"` to your ScrollView xml tag and simply add the below code to your `onCreate` function or any other place where you need it after you've set the text.

```
final ScrollView scrollView = ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView));
        scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
            }
        },100);
```

You can try to use `post()` instead of `postDelayed()` like this:

```
final ScrollView scrollView = ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView));
        scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
            }
        });
```

It does not have a delay, but this can lead to problems in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

See this

```
ScrollView scr = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scr);
scr.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```

Comment: This requires `API Level 21` and i am using 14 as minimum `API`   is there is any other solution  ?

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.oss.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/src"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp">

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/content" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I want this `LinearLayout` in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the scrollview.

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: also add  android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to the parent layout